# How to insert a space before and after a character and put on a new line in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, line

I need to insert a character before x1 and after x1 and put on a new line

my code:

```
f='p11p21p31'
y='x1'
k=str(y).join(f[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(f), 3))
#p=' '.join(k[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(k), 3))
print(k)
```

My outout

```
p11x1p21x1p31
```

I need:

```
p11 x1
p21 x1
p31 x1
```

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there. Using your code:

```
f='p11p21p31'
y='x1'
k=str(" "+y+"\n").join(f[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(f), 3))+" "+y
print (k)
```

Output:

```
p11 x1
p21 x1
p31 x1
```

You need to join with a linebreak after your delimiter, and a space preceding that delimiter. You finally add space+delimiter at the end of your string, cause `join()` on list will not set your delimiter after the last element.

Alternatively:

```
k= "".join([f[i] if (i+1) % 3 != 0 else f[i]+" "+y+"\n" for i in range(0,len(f))])
```

In a function:

```
f='p11p21p31'
y='x1'

def split_fxy(f,x,y):
    return "".join([f[i] if (i+1) % x != 0 else f[i]+" "+y+"\n" for i in range(0,len(f))])

print (split_fxy(f,3,y))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing with join is that it will only add `'x1'` between elements you want to join ([see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)). To fix it, you will need to add an extra `" x1"` at the end.

If you are using Python 3.6+ (which is highly recommended) use the following:

```
f='p11p21p31'
y='x1'
k= f' {y}\n'.join(f[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(f), 3)) + f' {y}'
print(k)
```

If you are using a version prior version to 3.6, use:

```
f='p11p21p31'
y='x1'
k= ' {}\n'.format(y).join(f[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(f), 3)) + ' ' + y
print(k)
```

The previous code will work also even in the case you use Python2 which at this point is strongly discouraged.

**Output:**

```
p11 x1
p21 x1
p31 x1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `join` the `\n`.

```
f = 'p11p21p31'
y = 'x1'
size = 3  # split each 3 chars

k = '\n'.join(f[i:i+size] + ' ' + y for i in range(0, len(f), 3))
print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `f` string to make you intent more clear:

```
f='p11p21p31'
y='x1'
print(''.join([f'{f[i:i+3]} {y}\n' for i in range(0,len(f),3) ]))
```

Prints:

```
p11 x1
p21 x1
p31 x1
```

Answer (score 0):

With a regex based solution

1/ split according to your pattern

2/ filter null item

3/ concat  x1 to all item

4/ join with \n

```
import re

f='p11p21p31'
#      4                3                         2          1
print("\n".join(map(lambda i: i+" x1", list(filter(None, re.split(r'([a-z]*[0-9]+)', f))))))
```